# Quantum Thrusters and Warp Drives

Tags: quantum-mechanics, space-travel, warp-drives

Any reservations about the potential of this (given in the link below/title above)?
Does it seem like a helpless attempt or something which might have the potential of developing into something real?

http://news.discovery.com/space/quantum-thruster-warp-drive-physics-130823.htm

Comment: the link i posted is less than 2 months old. this question is a year old.

Comment: The idea of merging QM & the Alcbuierre warp drive is years old. You asked if this is feasible idea, the question I proposed as a duplicate more-or-less asks this as well. The link also provides an answer as to why this idea is *not* feasible.

Answer (score -3):

The idea is very much possible by using exotic matter through quantum waves amongst other things of course. Besides the energy was scaled down in caparison to Voyager 1 size and achieves this by using a ring around the ship. Sure this may not be feasible now ,but so many other things were considered impossible before they were created. The equation that made the warp drive even possible was created by the physicist Alcubierre and later made in the realm of possibility by Dr. Harold White. One could speculate that the negative energy required could be made by using the Casmir effect or a antimatter reactor using plasma or lasers. The argument that it can be feasible at any point is speculative and cannot be dismissed as an entirely impossible idea.

Comment: *later made in the realm of possibility by Dr. Harold White.* No, he really hasn't. White's gone public with hopes to *make* it real, but he's not actually done anything with it

Comment: This answer seems somewhere between fairly useless and wrong, since it says the idea is speculative (of course, since it doesn't exist yet) and can't be ruled out (may or may not be true).